# Is Mr. Robot Real?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, mr-robot

The older *fsociety* dude with the specs, that recruits Elliot on the train.. And pushes Elliot off the pier onto the rocks or whatever it is that happened. Is he *real*,  Elliot's *alter ego?* Or some kind of *hallucination?* If he is just some kind of *mental manifestation*, is Elliot actually aware of it?

Clues:

- He doesn't seem to have a name, despite playing a *pivotal role* in the *plot*, and being a *crucial part* of the *story*.
- Nobody seems to mention him, despite the fact that he appears to be *in charge* of *fsociety's* whole *operation.*
- The *accident* gets treated like a *suicide attempt* by the hospital staff, the psychologist, and Elliot himself.
- Elliot will speak directly to the viewer, mention our apparent non-existence, and making light of the situation.
- The few people he gets close to, generally seem to be confused by his behaviour.